# How do I create (alloc/initwithImage) a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is this the proper way to allocate and initialize a UIBarButton item with an image?

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:@"back_topbtn.png" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
```

Comment: think right. but why not u have a action. without action what will u do with a button?

Answer (score 3):

No this not correct way, you are not using image object you are putting your image name here.so this shows a warning to you

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_topbtn.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
```

this is the correct way to use it, also this is not more than an image when you are not declaring any action. so declare any action(use selector).

Answer (score 2):

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *btnImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image-name"];
[btn setImage:btnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, btnImg.size.width, btnImg.size.height);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(whatever) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach is to use an UIImage. It makes sense to do this in your `- initWithNibName:bundle:` method.

Here is en example to add an image button to the right. Note that `myButtonTapped:` will be called when the button is tapped, be sure to implement it.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"My title";

        UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(myButtonTapped:)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myButton;
        [myButton release];
    }
    return self;
}
```